# Proper structure of Connection string in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, connection-string

What should be the proper structure of Connection string in C# to access SQL Server 2008 R2 over internet using the public ip of the server ?
I used the below connection string . It works fine within our network using local IP but when i am trying to acces it over internet with public IP, I am getting error.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tcp:192.168.0.16,49582;Initial Catalog=TrulyDB;uid=sa;pwd=sa@pass123;");
```

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: It may be that firewall is obstructing connection from public IP.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: And what happens if you use [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct the connection string? Also, can you get to the server if you try to access it with Management Studio or similar tool? It sounds to me like you have a firewall problem.

Comment: This link may be helpful, http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
There are different ways to Create Connection String which depends on 
Authentication type as you know 
1.> Windows Authentication 
2.> SQL Server Authentication
```

[Follow this link](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sqlconnection-connection-string.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.16,49582;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=TrulyDB;uid=sa;pwd=sa@pass123;");
```